# run a php command from a textbox form

Tags: php, preg-replace, eval

I'm trying to make a bb code option for running php code from a database text field. 
something like `[?php]code[/?]`

I know it's not safe, but nobody can edit the pages, and I mainly want to use it to let it calculate things or include a file.

This is what I have sofar:

```
$txt = preg_replace("#\[?php\](.+?)\[/?\]#is", eval("\\1"), $txt);
```

Comment: Then really - you should find ways to do that without running arbitrary code.  Want to do a calculation, user a parser for what's inside the BB Tags, want to include a file, use a syntax specifically for that.  Allowing it with the assumption that no one can edit it is based on falsehood, and opens up your server to be vulnerable if your database is ever compromised.

Comment: How would I include a file in this way then?

Answer (score 0):

The example you provided does not work as `eval()` evaluates before `preg_replace()`, and the result is actually used as a replacement. `\\1` is not a valid PHP expression, so I expect that the given code will return a parse error.

You should use `preg_match()` first to extract a PHP expression, then `eval()` it, and only then replace the text between bb tags with the result of the `eval()`.

That said, as commented above, I personally would strongly not recommend doing anything like that. This basically provides an arbitrary access to your server, and is a very bad design idea in any way. I guess you really need only a certain number of operations, like including a page from a particular directory. You could implement dedicated bb tags specifically for those limited number of operations with all precautions.

Comment: How would you make an include tag then? As I can't find anything other than eval to run php

Answer (score 0):

You can start buffering, `eval` whole string, closing php tag first, and get buffer as variable:

```
$txt = "Result of 2+2 = [?php] echo 4; [/?].";

$txt = str_replace(array('[?php]', '[/?]'), array('<?php','?>'), $txt);
ob_start();
eval('?>'.$txt);
$txt = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

echo $txt;
```